# Class variable initialization?

Tags: python, initialization, class-variables

Is there a **init**() method for the class (not for the instance).
What I want is to set class variable value (it is expensive operation) the first time an instance is created.
Something like :

```
class Blah:
  abc = None

  def __init__(self):
    if Blah.abc is None : Blah.abc = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Why didn't your example work?

Comment: You could probably fool around with a metaclass and get it to do what you want.  Here is a start - [Python metaclasses by example](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/14/python-metaclasses-by-example)

Comment: Or maybe [Using Decorators to Patch Class Definitions](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch09.html#_discussion_154) (Python Cookbook) - about one-third of the way down on that page

Comment: I wrote it on the fly.. it seems it does not work in ipython, but work if stored in a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> class Blah:
...     abc = None
...     def __init__(self):
...       if Blah.abc is None:
...           Blah.abc = [1,2,3]
... 
>>> print(Blah.abc)
None
>>> foo = Blah()
>>> print(Blah.abc)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what's in the question?